# Open / Close menu on button click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I just ran into a problem. On my site I need to have possibility to open or close menu item by  click of the button.

On button click :

```
var checked = true;


function NotifierButtonClicked() {
    if (checked == true) {
        checked = false;

        GetNotificationsForUser();

        $('.selectBox').slideToggle(200).css('borderTop', 'none');
        $('.selectBox li').click(function () {
            $('.selectBox').slideUp(200);
        });


    }
    if (checked == false) {
        checked = true;
        $('.selectBox').slideUp(200);
    }

}
```

So problem here is that when I enter `if block` first time, `checked` is true, so I slide menu up and set `checked` to be true. Next time I click on button checked is true so menu will open up, but I set checked to be false so when code gets to next if condition it will run too and close menu right away. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd do it like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/DxV4P/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if` and then `else if`

```
function NotifierButtonClicked() {
    if (checked == true) {
        // code
    } else if (checked == false) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (checked) { ... }else{ ... }` would be enough!

Comment: @adeneo Yes I agree with you. I just want to show exactly where the error occurs.